# Simple JQuery show/hide text button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I'm trying to practice with JQuery, so I made a simple program...or tried to.  There is a button that, when clicked, hides the only

element on the page.  That works fine.  But when I click it again, it doesn't bring the paragraph back and change the button text back, as its supposed to.  And there any way I can get this to work without using two buttons?  Here's what the script looks like right now:

```
 <script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var t;
    $("button").click(function(){

      if (t === "off") {
         $("p").show();
         $(this).text("hide text");
      }

      $("p").hide();
      $(this).text("show text");
      t = "off";  
    });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var t = "on"; 
$("button").click(function(){

  if (t === "off")
  {
      $("p").show();
      $(this).text("hide text");
      t = "on";
  }
  else
  {
      $("p").hide();
      $(this).text("show text");
      t = "off";  
  }
});

});
```

Something like that. basically the `$("p").hide` part always triggers.

Or even easier, use `toggle` function

Comment: Thanks...the worked.  But strange, I could have sworn I tried something like that earlier.

Comment: @DennisMarkham likely reason for beginners is the braces doesn't line up correctly. Javascript suffers from that quite a lot

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to put the `hide` logic in `else`:

```
if (t === "off") {
    $("p").show();
    $(this).text("hide text");
} else {
    $("p").hide();
    $(this).text("show text");
    t = "off";
}
```

In your code, when you "click it again", although `t` is `off` and `$("p")` is made to shown at beginning, it would be immediately made to `hide` again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var t; 
$("button").click(function(){

  if (t === "off")
  {  
      $(this).text("hide text");
       t = "";  
  } else {      
   $(this).text("show text");
   t = "off";  
   }
$("p").toggle();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<p>Paragraph text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers that have already provided to you, so I'm just going to point out things that I think could be done better.

1. You need to put the part of the code below in an `else` statement, otherwise this block of code will execute regardless of the value of `t`. I suggest you learn more about if-else conditional statement.

   ```
    $("p").hide();
    $(this).text("show text");
    t = "off";
   ```
2. `$("button").click(function(){` you should use `id` of the button, i.e. `$("#nameOfButtonID").click(function(){`. Learn about the `id` or `class` attribute in html. `id` is a unique way identify which button to handle the click event.
3. `t` could be treated as `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

In your button click function you have to return before the if loop exits and you need to set some other value or undefined to t.

Order of execution:
First click:

1. t value is "undefined"
2. if loop wont execute
3. hide "p"
4. set button value as 'show text' and t as "off"

Second click:

1. t value is "off"
2. if loop will execute
3. it will show 'p'
4. change button value to 'hide text'

   ---- here you should change t's value and return----
5. As there is no return 'p' will hide
6. button text will be 'show text' again.

   ```
   $("button").click(function() {
      if (t === "off") {
        $("p").show();
        $(this).text("hide text");
        //add the below code
        t = undefined;
        return;
       }
      $("p").hide();
      $(this).text("show text");
      t = "off";
   });
   ```